# @BeforeAll alternatives in SpringBoot tests

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, transactions, spring-boot-test, junit-jupiter

I have a code snippet for populating the H2 db before my integration tests. I put my code in a @BeforeAll method. I would like to use my own Service for doing this, because I find this is the most comfortable and robust way (when persistent layer changes during development, plus I can easily reference Entities when creating other Entities). In BService.create() method, I validate entityA (and call a getter on entityB of course). However, I got `LazyInitializationException`.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyControllerTest {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void initH2(@Autowired EntityAService aService, 
    @Autowired EntityBService bService) {
        EntityA a = aService.create(new EntityA("a"));
        EntityB b = new EntityB("b");
        b.setEntityA(a);
        bService.create(b);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ksteindl.domain.entities.EntityB.entityA, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

EntityB reference EntityA with a LAZY manner for a reason, I don't want to change it.
I know the code is OK, because when it is called via Controller (bService.create(b)), the validation doesn't throw exception. With `@BeforeEach` it doesn't throw Exception either, but that is only a workaround, I don't want to run the init code before each and every test case. `@Transactional` annotation doesn't help.
Do you know some solution for this problem? It seems SpringBoot container isn't fully functional when this code runs. I've tried implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` but got the same error. I need very similar to @BeforeAll, but when a the container is in a fully functioning state. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the entire test class setup. Are you using `@SpringBootTest` for this test, or `@DataJpaTest`?

Comment: Sure, I have extended with the class setup, thanks.